# Что работает быстрее в C# - DataSet+DataTable или SQLiteDataReader?

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, sqlite, sqlite3

пишу на С# поиск по КЛАДР и возник вопрос оптимизации, что лучше использовать чтобы быстро находить записи в локальной базе данных SQLite, DataSet+DataTable или SQLiteDataReader?

Comment: Для быстрого поиска лучше оптимизировать SQL запросы и расставить где надо индексы.

Comment: Ридер быстрее. Но он однопроходный. Если нужно обрабатывать данные несколько раз, то сохранение их в DataTable или типизированную коллекцию необходимо.